# Woocommerce questions flooding WPSE

Tags: support, woothemes

I've lately become very involved in WPSE. One thing I noticed is that the side gets overflowed by woocommerce question. Somedays about 70 percent is woocommerce related.

To my understanding, woocommerce is a third party plugin, which according to site rules and my understanding are are off topic.

My question/questions are, why are some questions flagged as off topic and are accepted as such, and some are rejected.

My feeling on woocommerce is that all questions should be off topic, and the tag should be removed. It will be best to create another stackexchange site just for woocommerce questions. I know this is going off topic now, but coming back to tags, shouldn't the wordpress.com tag also be removed. Wordpress.com questions is also according to me, off-topic, as wordpress.com have their own forum for questions.

This is my point of view, and I would like to hear whether my points raised are valid or not, and what the reasons being if my points aren't valid

Comment: You can add WooCommerce tags to your ignore list - via `sidebar -> Favorite Tags -> edit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To my understanding, woocommerce is a third party plugin, which according to site rules and my understanding are are off topic.

True.

> My question/questions are, why are some questions flagged as off topic and are accepted as such, and some are rejected.

Those left open usually have potential to be reworked as generic. Mods have binding close vote and try to not use it to lightly.

> My feeling on woocommerce is that all questions should be off topic, and the tag should be removed.

Tag *was* removed for a bit, then was restored. See the discussions on meta.

> It will be best to create another stackexchange site just for woocommerce questions.

While no such site is being planned at Area51, they are working on their own QA site much like it. We were asked to refrain from sending people there why they are working out details, but as soon as that is officially live we will be dumping **everything** WooCommerce from here in that direction.

> I know this is going off topic now, but coming back to tags, shouldn't the wordpress.com tag also be removed.

It's not nearly as much of a problem and sometimes the tag helps to see that asker is in wrong place (and not waste time answering for wrong environment) without other identifying details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rarst. Just for interest now, did woocommerce drop anything when their site will be ready. I also think your point on the wordpress.com tag is valid, never thought of it that way.

Comment: @PieterGoosen they are working on it, we are poking with is-it-done-yet periodically, no worries :)

Comment: Great. Thank you for keeping up a great site like WPSE.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I just hang out here, thank SE team for keeping it up :)

Comment: @Rarst is it different than the Community you posted in a previous discussion?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee that's the one

Comment: Looks like there is a proposed Area 51 site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80132/woocommerce. I've started following it and added my quota 5 sample questions