# Is It Open Season On WooCommerce Questions Yet?

Tags: discussion

I've been spending more time in the review queues lately, and ran into a string of WooCommerce questions. While this has been discussed in Meta previously ([Woocommerce questions flooding WPSE](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/woocommerce-questions-flooding-wpse), among others). If these questions were asked on more obscure plugins, they would be closed. Should we be taking the same stand for this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one just got to them before you?.. :) I am not sure what's your question about them is. If they are specific too WooCommerce then not in scope, etc. Business as usual.

Comment: Referred them for close...they were exclusively WooCommerce.

Answer (score 2):

We do get quite a lot of third party plugin related questions, specially woocommerce (due to their own poor/non-existing support). We are currently cleaning the site up of third party plugin support related questions. Have you read [this post](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3889/31545). If you haven't, please do, and don't just read it, please take part.

I have noticed that you are actively taking part in the review queues, thanks for that. It is really up to us as members to keep our site constructive.

Whenever you do a first post review, or just browsing around, and a question is about a support issue to a third party plugin or a third party theme (remember, the bundled themes are not third party themes, they form part of wordpress), flag it for our attention, and downvote it. Everyone with 3K+ reputation have a say if a question must be closed or not, so we will take the issue further in either closing or rejecting the flag :-).

Comment: Pieter - I've seen the post. I'm trying my hand at doing some reviews, I'm a better editor.  I'm was more suited for the old WPSE as I'm more of a hyper-Power user, than a Dev, but I'll do what I can.

Comment: No problem :-) Every single input is appreciated. Enjoy